# How to cross compile C code for an ia188em chip

Tags: c, compiler-construction, embedded

I inherited an old project that uses an Innovasic ia188em processor (previously AM188 from AMD). I will likely need to modify the code, and so will need to recompile. Unfortunately, I'm not sure which compiler was used previously (it compiled into a .hex file), and searching through the source code (and in particular the header files) doesn't seem to indicate it either.

I did see one program that could work, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any free programs that might do this. I saw some forums where people said they thought either an old Borland compiler or Bruce's C Compiler may work with 80188 chips (which I assume my chip falls under?), but nothing concrete. I failed to compile with Borland C++ 5 when I tried, though I admit I probably didn't have it set up correctly.

This is for an embedded board (i.e. no OS). I don't program too often, so my compiler knowledge is limited. I mostly just write simple C programs and compile with gcc under linux. Any help is appreciated.

**Updated 10/8: I apologize, I was looking at both this code, and the PC side code that talks to the embedded board, and got mixed up. The code for the ia188em (embedded board) is actually C (not C++). Updated title to reflect that. I'm not sure if it makes a huge difference or not.**

Comment: Recreating the original tool chain with no information on it is going to be a pretty big job. I'd start with the tools recommended by the manufacturer of the embedded board. That's probably what was used. Convert the HEX file to binary and sweep it for text strings. It's possible one of the tools stamped the file with its name -- a valuable clue. (Or, failing that, any interesting looking strings can be punched into your favorite search engine, hopefully providing a lead.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My company is the manufacturer of the board (well, it is made and populated elsewhere, but it is our design), but the original engineer is long gone, as is a lot of documentation and software (if there ever was documentation). The ROM used is an AM27c010 (128k x 8bit), and we have the programmer for it. I did try to contact Innovasic (e-mail and phone call) about recommended compilers for their chip, but never got a response.
I converted the hex to binary (hex2bin), but only saw strings internal to the program itself, nothing about any compiler tools. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A little web searching indicates that until the last few versions, GCC/Binutils could be kludged to work for real-mode x86, **provided** that no pointer operations extended beyond a single segment.  So if you can fit in 64K, or craft assembly language accessors for anything that needs to cross such a boundary, that could work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a 16 bit "real mode" x86 compiler.  If your compiler is a DOS targeted compiler, you will need some means of generating a raw binary rather than than MS-DOS load module (.exe), this may be possible through linker options or may require a non-DOS linker.

Any build scripts or makefiles included with the project code might help you identifier the toolchain used, but the likelihood is that it is no longer available, and you'll need to source "antique software".

Comment: I think back in the day, there was a path where you could convert a *suitably layed out* .exe to .com, and from there to .hex.  I'm not sure if the DOS-ish 0x100 starting address remained, but even if it did, it wouldn't be hard to write something which modified the binary or hex to add machine code to jump to there from whatever the expected entry point is.

Answer (score 0):

When I used to do this sort of thing (1985 -> 1990) I used the intel toolchain, now long obsolete and no longer available from intel.  The tools required were

- iC-86 - The compiler
- link-86 - the linker
- loc-86 - the image locater.

There is some information on these tools at a [very old site here](http://wolverine.caltech.edu/tools/).

Another method that was used at the time was to process the .exe file produced by a Microsoft standard real mode PC compiler (MS-Pascal was the language used on that project) into an absolutely located image that could be blown into EPROM.  The tool used for the conversion was proprietary to the company so I have no idea whether there is an equivalent available